# What is the difference between close question under review and under tools?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close, vote-count

What is the difference between the both **close** options:

- Review->close votes (40 a day)
- Tools->close question (on the right side of the screen)

Apparently the one under the second option do not count in the counter of the first one ( under recent reviews) where do they count? do both share any counter?

Comment: Review queue is accessible to 3k+ (?) rep users, while the Tool is only available to 10k+ rep users. Review queue just contains the question with close votes, while the Tool > close questions contains questions with "doesn't belong here or duplicate" flag.

Answer (score 2):

The only main difference is: if you close any question from the Review queue it will considered as a review (your review count will be increased). While from the Tools your review count will not be increased.

From the Review queue you can *review* only 40 questions/day. Review can be either *close* or *leave open* or *edit*. While from the Tools you can close questions as per your [close limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/187824).

Comment: Is there any counter for the ones i vote to close from tools?

Comment: @OneMore - There isn't any special counter (like review counter) for tools. Only one counter is [your close votes count](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/158273/onemore?tab=votes&sort=closure "Link for OP only") (your closing votes will be increased).